# How to put DbSet and Seed in one transaction (Entity Framework)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, revert

The `DbContext`'s `DbSet`s are executed but one of the tables doesn't get created. Then the seed method runs filling all the tables with data without the table that didn't get created.

Is there a way not to execute the seed method and revert the created tables and all the created database if one of the tables in the `DbContext` didn't get created?

Comment: With code first, to add a new table in DB, you can use code first migration to do that. More details see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: I meant Initial Migration with Initial Seed in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The Isolation Level and its scope is of your preference and the nature of your query

```
Public Shared Function Create(DbContext As DbContext) As YourDBname
    Dim _txoptions As New TransactionOptions()
    _txoptions.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
    Dim _tx = New Transactions.TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, _txoptions)

    Return New YourDBname(DbContext)
End Function
```